# How Do I Create An Email Event With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Basically i'm creating a website for a friend and he needs a "Contact Us Page", i'm using bootstrap studio and I have a page where you enter your name, and email. But i'm having trouble with the next part. I need the page to open the client's default email program to compose to a certain address with the entered name and email already in it how would one go about this?

Comment: Make a link that goes to `mailto:username@domain`

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto

Answer (score -1, accepted):

simply do something like this

`<a href="mailto:myemail@emaildomain.com"> Click Here To Email! </a>`

if you want the email to be sent via a form submission you either need to setup a backend that will do that or you can use a service like https://formspree.io/

I've used them before, but I'm not certain what they're rules are about data privacy so its really up to you.